# What does a psychology research graduate need to develop to become ready for a career in UX/HCI?

Tags: interaction-design, career-development, ux-designer, jobs

If I have a research psychology master and I would like to get a job in UX design or Human Interaction computer how can I do it? Or where I could start?

Comment: This isn't a UX question; it's a careers advice one. And it's not really a question with a single, canonical 'correct' answer. Everyone is going to have a different opinion on this, none of which are more correct than the other.

Comment: There's general info on gaining experience on [Getting into UX as a CS graduate](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4670/). Many UX people I've worked with have psych backgrounds, it brings strong advantages: you've conducted research with human adult subjects, you understand sample sizes & research design, you already know principles like priming, attention, cognitive load, affordances... emphasise everything like this on resumes etc. Your main skill gaps will include experience and knowledge of tech trends and design patterns: join groups, follow blogs, do projects in your own time, etc.

Comment: I've suggested an edit to the title of this question to be a little more specific and answerable *(I'm a little surprised it was closed: UX professionals with psychology backgrounds and psych-grad colleagues can give factual answers based on their professional experience of what they and their colleagues use from their degrees, and what skill gaps they needed to fill compared to colleagues from other backgrounds. This site even has a "**career development**" tag...)*